# PHP document upload form - error message

Tags: php

I am getting the following message on a PHP document upload form i created:

Warning: fread(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in

/home/admin/upload.php on line 129

Warning: fread(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in

/home/admin/upload.php on line 131

Here is my code, line 129 and 131 are commented on:

```
<?
if(isset($_POST['upload']))
{
        $fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
        $tmpName  = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
        $fileSize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
        $fileType = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];

        $fp = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
            $content = fread($fp, $fileSize); //Line 129
        $content = addslashes($content);
                fclose($fp); //Line 131

        if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
        {
            $fileName = addslashes($fileName);
        }
        $fileName = str_replace(' ','_',$fileName);

        //MySQL Database Connect
include '../includes/dblogin.php';


        $query = "INSERT INTO upload_min (name, size, type, content, types ) ".
                 "VALUES ('$fileName', '$fileSize', '$fileType', '$content', 'minutes')";

        mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');                  

        echo "<p align='center'>File $fileName uploaded</p> <p align='center'><a href='index.php'>Go back to Admin</a></p>";
}       
?>
```

my users are only uploading MS word documents. so i dont know if it is because the file name could be too long...

i have a page that calls the dbase and displays the files and there are .doc and .docx files.... so i dont think the file extension is an issue... plust i just uploaded a .pdf file and it worked fine...

anyone?

Comment: Don't you have this `@` symbol in your real code?

Comment: What @ symbol? but no, i do not have an @ symbol in my code. HOWEVER i did find that uploading .docx documents seems to corrupt them when i try to download them from the display page.... is docx not a recognized file extension?

Comment: Could it be that the server does not support that file extension, thus not a valid stream resource?

Answer (score 0):

Are the files is it erroring on larger than the `upload_max_filesize` parameter in your php.ini?

Comment: i do not have a upload_max_filesize parameter in my php.ini file... didnt know that was necessary...

Answer (score 0):

Did you try var_dump-ing the $_FILES superglobal? Is there actually a filename there? Did you set `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form?

Besides, your first line should be more like:

```
if (isset($_FILES['userfile']) && $_FILES['userfile']['error'] == 0)
```

EDIT:

Also, I really hope you're escaping $content and all the other variables before inserting them into the database.

Comment: yes, the enctype is there.  yes the file name is there.  the file gets put into the dbase, and i can see it on the display page where i call it.  i can even click the link and download it, but the .docx files are saying that they are corrupt...so somewhere from my form to the server, something isnt working. pretty vague eh?

Comment: Then your whole post is totally misleading. You don't have problem with the upload at all. Your question should be "Uploaded files getting corrupted in the database." or something. See my edit.

Comment: What's the nonsense in your edit section? wipe it. the rest of your answer is perfect

Comment: @netcoder - first my apologies for not clearly explaining my issue.  im still fairly new at PHP.  so would my line then read: $content = file_get_contents($fp, $filesize);  ?

Comment: @Tony as a matter of fact, it's impossible to have your file in the database if you get that error message. Sort things out first.

Comment: @netcoder and my apologies, but would i use this mysql_real_escape_string()
in my INSERT statement?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel thats not what im seeing.  I browse a document.  I hit the "upload" button, that error comes up, but also echos the statment that it was uploaded.  I go back to my display page and its on the page linked and able to be downloaded. So it is possible obviously.

Comment: EDIT Note: i have a hidden input with name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" and value="2000000" in my form.

Comment: So where should i put them then?  I need to be able to retrive them, and display them, or have my client be able to delete them on her admin page... im not sure what other way i can accomplish what i am doing with document storage and retrieval and display.

Comment: @tony I don't understand you. But it seems you have doubled your code somewhere. File cannot be saved if this error occurred. This error says that file contents weren't read. Anyway, better do not put your files in the database at all.

Comment: @tony save it in the disk directory

Answer (score 0):

Check these variable of PHP ini 
   * file_uploads
    * upload_max_filesize
    * max_input_time
    * memory_limit
    * max_execution_time
    * post_max_size

The first one is fairly obvious if you set this off, uploading is disabled for your installation.

http://www.radinks.com/upload/config.php

After proper configuration of ini . print the $_FILE variables.
Most probably file path is wrong  and file is not readable .

Check permissions also.

http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_file_upload.asp